# Prevent body from scrolling when opening side menu via CSS Transform

Tags: css, scrolltop, css-transforms

I'm currently working on a new site that utilizes side menus like the old Facebook app. My menus are opening properly, but if I'm scrolled down the page at all, the content scrolls back to the top of the page, rather than staying in it's current scrolled position.

Example: http://staging.michalekbrothersracing.com/ (scroll down a little ways and click on the "Our Partners" button)

Has anyone else had this issue.? Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Add `e.preventDefault()` to your `click` functions in your `side-nav.js` script. Without that, the browser fires the default behavior of the `#` link which, since it's not defined on the page, is the top of the page.

```
$( "#open-right" ).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#open-right").css("display", "none");
    $("#close-right").css("display", "block");
});

$( "#close-right" ).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#open-right").css("display", "block");
    $("#close-right").css("display", "none");
});
```